# How to create multiple unittest reports by executing each unittest only once?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, runner

I need multiple output formats from my unittest cases..

1. HTML output
2. XML output

Currently I need to execute all test cases multiple times with

1. [HTML Test Runner](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner_0_8_2/HTMLTestRunner.py) for HTML output
2. [XML Test Runner](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srittau/xmltestrunner/v0.2/xmlrunner.py) for XML output

This is because result object is bound with each TestCase and I couldn't found how can I bind list of result classes to each TestCase...(which may actually solve my problem)